# Read text from .txt file on Android internal storage as string

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to read a `.txt` file from the Android internal storage to a `string` variable.

But when I try to load the string, I get this error:

```
Cannot convert multipart to String
```

Comment: You're missing the most important part - the code you use to read a file. It's not possible to fix something you can't see. It would be just guessing.

Comment: Please supply enough information to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Eg: The code.

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you have a .txt file in your android's "internal storage"

To read a file from **internal storage**

> Call openFileInput() and pass it the name of the file to read. This
>   returns a FileInputStream. Read bytes from the file with read(). Then
>   close the stream with close().

```
   FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("test.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String line;
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line);
   }
   bufferedReader.close();
```

if your file is on your **sd card**

```
//Find the directory for the SD Card
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file 
File file = new File(sdcard,"test.txt");

//Read text from file 
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    } 
    br.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here 
}
```